# Pass React-Native bundled image to native module

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to write a native module for React-Native that can process images and it has to be possible for the JS code to pass in bundled images. By bundled images I am referring to the type the type of image that can be set as the source of an Image component using require.

This would be very straight forward if there was a way to get a native file path for those bundled images but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. I guess some other fancy React-Native way of passing images would also work but I have seen no mention of something like this either.

PS. At the moment I am busy with the Android module but I want it to work on iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoded image 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

```
<Image
  style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
  source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}}
/>
```

Can be inefficient for large images though

Comment: How on earth does that get it to the native side?